# Send XML file to web server in Android

Tags: java, xml, android, apache, http

I am planning on converting some longitude and latitude values to XML and then sending the file to a web server to display on a Google Map Interface.

Is it possible to send an XML file to a web server through my own application in Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a public class called [`HttpPost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) that would work fine.

Basically you specify the url that the server that you are sending the HTTP request to and the content of the XML goes into the POST area. The web server will receive the request and, assuming a php script is at the URL, the script can grab the contents via its own `$_POST` global variable and do with the XML what needs to be done.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Just make a http post with your xml data. You need a web server script that handles the xml you posted to the server aswell.

A guide
http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=1969